# BufferedReader read() and readLine() both hang trying to get a response from a POP3 server

Tags: java, network-programming, pop3

I'm developing a small terminal app that handles interactions with a POP3 server. However, I'm having a problem where both read() and readLine() from BufferedReader block. My initial attempts used readLine(), but after reading on SO and other sites, I figured that the **server isn't returning the appropriate characters to mark the end of the line, so I attempted to use read(). But for some reason, that blocks as well.**

```
    Socket s = new Socket(InetAddress.getByName(this.HOST), 110);

    BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(s.getInputStream()));
    PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(s.getOutputStream(), true);

    String res = in.readLine(); // This works fine
    System.out.println(res);

    res = "";
    char [] charRes = new char[1024];

    out.println("USER " + this.username);
    // res = in.readLine();
    in.read(charRes); // Does not work
    res = charRes.toString();
    System.out.println(res);
```

The problem is not with the server because I tested it using Telnet and it works fine. I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong and I would appreciate any help.

My client software is running on a Linux system and I am connecting to a Windows server.

Comment: Why aren't you using JavaMail?

Comment: This is a practical assignment for a networks class. I may not use anything other than sockets.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [the documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/InputStream.html#read(byte%5B%5D)), the `read(byte[])` method will block until at least one byte has been read from the stream.

To ensure there is data available before calling the `read(byte[])` method, you can call the `available()` method, [documented here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/InputStream.html#available()).

Based on your original question and the subsequent comments, the main problem seems to be caused by the line endings.  You have indicated that the client is running on Linux, where the standard line ending is `LF` (`\n`) but the [POP3 RFC](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1939#section-3) specifically requires each command to be terminated by `CRLF` (`\r\n`).  Instead of using `out.println()` (which will use your system line ending of `\n` automatically), try using the `PrintWriter.write(String)` ([documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/PrintWriter.html#write(java.lang.String))) method.

You appear to be using the `PrintWriter` constructor with `autoFlush` set to true.  This meant that your stream would be flushed automatically when using the `println()` method, HOWEVER, it will not flush automatically when using the `write()` method, so you will need to also add a call to `flush()`.  Again, it is advisable to refer to [the documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/PrintWriter.html#PrintWriter(java.io.OutputStream,%20boolean)). The updated code would look something like this:

```
out.write("USER " + this.username + "\r\n");
out.flush();
```

You may want to consider similarly updating your reads from the input stream to make sure you don't have to manually remove `\r` characters from the input (the various `readLine()` methods will consume / discard the `\n` but not the `\r` when the client runs on Linux).

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I have tried flush(), as well as (s.getInputStream()).available(), which returns 0 (which of course means it reached the end of the input stream). I even tried in.ready(), which returns false. I don't understand why this is the case. I know I'm not sending an incorrect request to the server because I copy-pasted in the terminal and it worked, so my guess is it might not be terminating the request properly. How should I go about fixing that?

Comment: Just to be clear, you are doing `out.flush()` correct?  As far as terminating the request, the [POP3 RFC](http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc1939#section-3) specifically requires for each command to be terminated by CRLF, but when you are calling `out.println()` the line will be terminated with either LF or CRLF depending on the platform / architecture.

Comment: I notice you are using the `PrintWriter` constructor with `autoFlush` set to `true` so I don't think your problem is going to be caused by a failure to flush the output stream.  The line endings seem the most likely culprit at this point.

Comment: Yes, I used `out.flush()`. I'm not sure if it's significant but I am running this code on a Linux machine, so I'm not sure if that might be a problem (as far as I know the server is run on Windows Server). Could the Windows server be sending CLRF while `BufferedReader` is waiting for LF?

Comment: Linux will send LF do line ending but pop3 server is waiting for CRLF as per the document from my previous comment. I will update the answer shortly based on this.